# Syntax Issue in Stylesheet

Tags: css, react-native, expo, react-native-ios

I am getting the following error on my simulator:

> Unexpected token(71:6)

and it's something to do with the styling portion of it.   After a long day of coding, I need a different pair of eyes to look at this. The const styles and the last semicolon are underlined with red.

I have removed commas, semi-colons where they originally were and placed them else where, but not luck. They are currently where they are suppose to be.

I expect to see the app to appear, stylized.

```js
     const styles = StyleSheet.create(
    {
      container: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: "center"

    },
    animatedHeaderContainer: {
      position: 'absolute',
      top: (Platform.OS == 'ios') ? 20 : 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center'
    },
    headerText: {
      color: 'white',
      fontSize: 22
    },
    item: {
      backgroundColor: '#ff9e80',
      margin: 8,
      height: 45,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center'
    },
    itemText: {
      color: 'black',
      fontSize: 16
    } 
  });
```

Comment: Can you share your style?

Comment: Hi @CarlosAbraham just added it.

Comment: You probably have an issue somewhere else, because it doesn't look to have any errors.

Comment: Where is it located? Please show me the full code with this.